# Center Nav Bar within div

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my navbar is stuck to the left of the screen. Any idea how to make it centered on the screen but not stretch the buttons to be 1/4 the width of the screen (I don't want the buttons to take up the entire screen, just the navbar background)

I `text-align: center` on the ul and `display: inline-block` on the li, not sure why it will not center in the main div.

```css
.topBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.3em;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.navBar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#mainNav ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#mainNav li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#mainNav li a {
  display: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #333333;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul#mainNav li a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <div class="topBar">
    <!-- Yellow Top Bar -->
  </div>
  <nav class="navBar">
    <div>
      <ul id="mainNav">
        <li><a href='#home'><span>HOME</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#sketches'><span>INITIAL SKETCHES</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#progress'><span>PROGRESS</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#final'><span>FINAL PRODUCT</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: How is the current situation different from what you need? I'm not sure I understand what the problem is, as what the snippet shows is what I understand you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `text-align: center;` to the `.navBar`, like this:

```
.navBar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333333;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: perfect! i knew it would be something so simple. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BootStrap 4 CSS from the CDN, then all you need to do is to wrap the contents inside your nav class using a div class container like this: `<div class="container">` and it would center your Nav bar menu to the center of your screen, while the nav bar itself extends to both ends of your visible space.

I have made a [Plnkr example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/THJdsqzJazkiRjA90GOm?p=preview) for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try adding the CSS example I have provided below:

```
.navBar {
  text-align: center; 
}
```